# Getting the URL from a dynamically generated page

Tags: php, dynamic, contact-form

I have a site with a page in it that dynamically pulls a family profile from a database that contains a bunch of family data.

The generated url looks something like this:
http://example.com/family/?name1-name2/

I have a contact form on this page, and I want to include the current url in each contact submission so that I can tell which family's page the form is coming from.

I don't know much php at all, I'm wondering what php can be used to grab the url.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get current URL of your page:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: And this will even grab the sections of the url after the '?'

Answer (score 0):

In general the $_SERVER variables will get you what you need. Try adding the following on your page to see what's available:

```
var_dump($_SERVER)
```

in general, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will do the job. It'd output `/family/?name1-name2/`